# Switch off a device to save energy

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp

I need to manage the device shutdown function programmatically to save energy (similarly as the Windows device manager).

How to programmatically uncheck the box "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
on the properties tab of "Power management" device in Device Manager?

It will be used on Windows XP.

I know that it's possible to turn on / off the device through SetupDi functions ... maybe I can do similarly with them, 
but I can not find how to implement this action.
Maybe someone has already faced with this problem.

Comment: tab of "Power management" https://yadi.sk/i/bFQuFssv3UHSdP

Comment: Ooh, that's positively ancient. Even Vista is out of support, but I managed to find an XP mention in some lingering Vista documentation. Apparently, before Vista you had `SPDRP_XYZ` identifiers in `<Setupapi.h>`. These identify properties; you'll need to find the right property ID for your property.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an API to control Power Management, not sure if it would be compatible with XP but here you go if it helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968807%28v=vs.85%29.aspx